# How to get Node value from XML using java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to find node value from XML and need to store in Database . But first trying to print the node value in console.

XML Content are:

```
<ServiceRouteInfo xmlns="http:..." xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ExtraDimensions xmlns:a="http://..">...</ExtraDimensions>
  <FreightDimensions xmlns:a="http:..." i:nil="true"/>
  <MapParams>...</MapParams>
  <MiniCruise xmlns:a="http:..." i:nil="true"/>
  <Operators>
    <OperatorList>
      <Code>NL</Code>
      <CompanyName>No</CompanyName>
      <DepartCode>AB</DepartCode>
      <DestCode>KI</DestCode>
    </OperatorList>
  </Operators>
</ServiceRouteInfo>
```

Code:

```
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/Ferries_RouteXml/Aberdeen - Kirkwall.xml"));

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        System.out.println("*************************");
        String expression = "/ServiceRouteInfo /Operators/OperatorList";
        //String expression = "ServiceRouteInfo[CoCode]";
        System.out.println(expression);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("CoCode :  " + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

        }           
        System.out.println("*************************");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   


}
```

I need only Code,DepartCode,DestCode value to print in console. pls help me..

Comment: And what is your question? Your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly access these values one by one if u use something like that:

```
String expression = "/ServiceRouteInfo /Operators/OperatorList/Code/text()";
String value = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit and here it is:

```
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/Ferries_RouteXml/Aberdeen - Kirkwall.xml"));


        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        System.out.println("*************************");
        String expression = "/ServiceRouteInfo/Operators/OperatorList/*";
        System.out.println(expression);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        String[] descriptions = {"Code", "CompanyName", "DepartCode", "DestCode"};
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            final Node item = nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println(descriptions[i]+":  " + item.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

        }
        System.out.println("*************************");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note line: `String expression = "/ServiceRouteInfo/Operators/OperatorList/*";`